# superuser openid query text is misleading

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid

> Superuser gave me this error when I tried to login:
>
> This is an OpenID we haven't seen before:
>
> *openid text here*
>
> Do you want to create a new Super User account with this OpenID?
>
> (If you want to associate this OpenID with an existing account, click Cancel, log in under your existing account, then click the New Login link on your user page.)

I think this is poorly written because the way to associate my account is to click "New Login" (opposite of what is written) and then choose associate with stackoverflow accounts.

Comment: +1 Yup I had to pause and think about this when I created my account.

Comment: I just had that problem

Comment: The first line of this question shouldn't be in the quote block.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, it should be clearer that even though you have an account on a sister site you'll still need to create a new account on SU, and then optionally associate it with the other accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it should say "that we haven't seen before *on superuser.com*" and "with an existing superuser.com account".

Comment: we say this now. Good suggestion btw.